# Unable to get ng-message to disappear when form is valid or reference form in controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers/resources have been able to help me.

I am trying to make a simple form in angular that will take a number and display a message if it is negative:

```
<div layout-padding ng-controller="BaseController as vm">
<form name="vm.mechanicalForm">
    <input type="number" min="0" name="test" ng-model="vm.building.numberOfChillers" required />
    <div ng-messages="vm.mechanicalForm.number.$error">
      <div ng-message="min">
        Test worked
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="vm.save()" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Additionally, when I save the form, I want the controller to log one message if the form is valid, and another if it is not valid:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMessages']);
export class BaseController {
public mechanicalForm;
public building;
constructor() {
    this.mechanicalForm = {};
    this.building = {
      'numberOfChillers': 0
    };
}

public save() {
    if (this.mechanicalForm.$valid) {
      console.log("This worked");
    }
    else {
      console.log("This did not work");
    }
}
}
app.controller('BaseController', BaseController);
```

But it seems like my controller is not able to see the form at all. According to everything I have read I seem to be writing the code correctly. My two questions are:

1: Why will the `ng-message` not disappear when my input is valid?

2: Why is my controller not able to see my form object?

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/nb123/pen/Mxoawb) Demonstrating my issue. I am using AngularJS 1.5.3

For reference, here are the resources I have referred to so far:

[How to use ng-messages](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html#basics-of-ngmessages)

[AngularJS form and control state](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)

[Using 'controller as' syntax](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html)

[common issues with ng-messages](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2781)

Comment: Use basic debugging techniques to see the value of the form when the save button is clicked.

Comment: I have already tried that approach only to see that the form value is either an empty object if I define it in the constructor of my controller or undefined if it is defined in the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div layout-padding ng-controller="BaseController as vm">
<form name="vm.mechanicalForm">
    <input type="number" min="0" name="test" ng-model="vm.building.numberOfChillers" required />
    ̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶e̶s̶=̶"̶v̶m̶.̶m̶e̶c̶h̶a̶n̶i̶c̶a̶l̶F̶o̶r̶m̶.̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶.̶$̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶"̶>̶
    <div ng-messages="vm.mechanicalForm.test.$error">
      <div ng-message="min">
        Test worked
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="vm.save()" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/o2vI2c0Ja2rTlSYYAtiy?p=preview)

Comment: That was a silly thing for me to miss. But that does not fix my problem. I realize the plunker is not working. This [code pen](https://codepen.io/nb123/pen/Mxoawb) illustrates my problem.

Comment: Works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/o2vI2c0Ja2rTlSYYAtiy?p=preview).